# Как сгенерировать изображение в Python?

Tags: python, opencv

Я могу загрузить изображение и вывести его на экран следующим образом:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
cv2.imshow("Original", img)
```

К примеру, чтобы получить белое изображение, я могу загрузить любое, нарисовать поверх него белый прямоугольник и вывести на экран.

Однако что делать, если я хочу получить белое изображение без предварительной загрузки?
Как заменить операцию загрузки операцией генерации объекта-изображения?

Comment: Вам принципиально `cv2` или пойдёт и `Pillow` как в ответе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Код ниже полностью [взят из документации](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Create a black image
img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)

# Draw a diagonal blue line with thickness of 5 px
cv2.line(img,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)

cv2.rectangle(img,(384,0),(510,128),(0,255,0),3)
cv2.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.ellipse(img,(256,256),(100,50),0,0,180,255,-1)

pts = np.array([[10,5],[20,30],[70,20],[50,10]], np.int32)
pts = pts.reshape((-1,1,2))
cv2.polylines(img,[pts],True,(0,255,255))

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(img,'OpenCV',(10,500), font, 4,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(10000)
```

Свеже-сделанный скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6):

Использовать Computer Vision Library для генерации изображений - это... странно. Используйте лучше [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/)

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (250, 250), (255, 255, 255))
img.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Тип возвращаемый `cv2.imread('1.jpg')` это `numpy.ndarray`. Чтобы создать аналогичную 300x400 белую картинку и показать её:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = np.full((300, 400, 3), 255, dtype=np.uint8) # create
cv2.imshow('300x400 white', img) # show
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Здесь [`numpy.full()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.full.html) просто создаёт массив заданной формы (3D: `300 400 3`) и типа (`uint8`) и заполняет его переданным (`255`) значением:

```
>>> np.full((3, 4), 5, dtype=int)
array([[5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5],
       [5, 5, 5, 5]])
```